# convergence of a sequence given by a finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given $p\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the sequence
$$x_n = \left( \frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}}{p} \right)^n.$$
I know it is bounded by $p^p$ and I guess there is a monotone behaviour, so it is convergent. In that case, how can I compute the limit? I wrote this
$$ \frac{x_n}{p^p} = \frac{1}{p^n} \left( \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{p/n} + \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)^{p/n} +...+\left( \frac{p}{p}\right)^{p/n}    \right)  ^n$$
which it seems a more easy expression, but **how can I proceed from here in order to get the limit?** Any hint is welcome. Besides if there is an easy way to get the limit I will be more than happy to know.

And a more general question: In order to calculate the limit of a convergent seguence, *what is the most effective technique?*.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I can't say what is *the most effective technique* to find the limit of a convergent seguence, it depends indeed case by case, in this one I would proceed as follows

$$\left( \frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}}{p} \right)^n=$$

$$=\left[\left(1+ \frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}-p}{p} \right)^{\frac{p}{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}-p}}\right]^{\frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}-p}{\frac p n}}$$

with

$$\left(1+ \frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}-p}{p} \right)^{\frac{p}{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}-p}} \to e$$

and by $\frac p n =x \to 0^+$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}-p}{\frac p n}=\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{1+2^x + 3^x + ... + p^x-p}{x}=$$

$$= \lim_{x\to 0 }\left(\frac{2^x-1}x + \frac{3^x-1}x+\ldots + \frac{p^x-1}x \right)=\log 2 +\log 3+\ldots+\log p=\log (p!)$$

therefore

> $$\left( \frac{1+2^{p/n} + 3^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n}}{p} \right)^n \to p!$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. There are two things I can't see. The first is why $$ \left( 1 + \frac{1+2^{p/n} + ... + p^{p/n} - p}{p}\right)\to e $$ and the second is why $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+2^x+...+p^x-p}{x} = log(p!).  $$ Can you give me a brief detail for each one? Again, thank you.

Comment: I know the rule $(1+1/n)^n \to e$, is there a more general rule?

Comment: @Senna Yes for any $f(x) \to \infty$ or $a_n \to \infty$ we can show that $(1+1/a_n)^{a_n} \to e$.

Comment: To prove the other limit we can use simply l'Hopital or the well known $$\frac{a^x-1}{x}\to \log a$$ notably we have $$\frac{1+2^x + 3^x + ... + p^x-p}{x} =\frac{2^x-1}x + \frac{3^x-1}x+\ldots + \frac{p^x-1}x$$ I've included also this detail in the answer.

Comment: @Senna Note that to avoid the first limit we can simply use that $$A^B = e^{B\log A}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! A very complete answer which from a learn a lot more than solve a concrete limit. +1